# Jquery focusout function on submit

Tags: jquery, forms, preventdefault

I am using focusout on an array of textboxes to validate that a user can't order more product than there is available. Everything works good when moving from textbox to textbox, but if one of the input boxes has focus and they click the submit button the focusout either does not fire or it does but the page submits before it can be stopped and bypasses the validation.

Is there a way to perform the focusout function if the form is submitted and stop the submission if they order too much?

Comment: If you could provide HTML code example (and the associated JS for better understanding of what you've done), I'd be glad to help ! Btw you should use JS only for UI controls "never trust user input", it's easily modifiable (and thus your validations would be useless)

Comment: It will not let me post the code. Too many characters error.

Comment: I will also validate on the server but I want to stop it before the submit actually happens and give the user feedback.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
function mysubmit() {
    alert("Form Submitted");
}
</script>
<form action="" onsubmit="mysubmit();return false">
    <input type="submit"  value="Save" />
</form>
```

You can submit the form using onsubmit handler instead direct submission through button.

Comment: Would this let the focusout fire before submitting?

Comment: If you're calling a function on foucusout and the condition that doesn't match, always return false. so that form will never submit until unless all the condition are met true.

Comment: If your query gets resolved, please accept the solution.